# Move an off-screen window back on-screen on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, desktop

I met the problem on move an off screen window back on-screen on mac. The application is Adobe Element 11 Organizer.
It can't be solve by adjust desktop resolution, or maximum the app window, or connect to a extra monitor. 
Since I can't add a possible answer due to reputation limit, start a new question here.

Comment: I merged the questions for you.